# Hessian with large binary data (java)

Tags: java, binary-data, hessian

I am looking for a complete example of large binary data transfer with Hessian (java) caucho implementation.

Where can I found one ?

Comment: What are you asking for? A data transfer method or an algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Tried this?

http://hessian.caucho.com/doc/hessian-overview.xtp#Hessian with large binary data