# Sending a file from server to client through web service

Tags: java, web-services

I want to send a .rar file from Server to Client through web service.Which data type to be return from server side method?There is no byte[] method if I am not wrong.

Kindly advice to solve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [Java web service to transfer file to Local system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810746/java-web-service-to-transfer-file-to-local-system)

You could also use a servlet ([Implementing a simple file download servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442893/file-download-servlet)) or send your file Base64 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I think byte[] is a JAX-WS supported type, see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnazc.html. JAX-WS will automatically convert byte[] into xsd:hexBinary string.